# String as a condition in a filter

Tags: python, python-polars

In my program, I want the user to be able to pass a string as a condition. For example, if the user input is "col(X) | col(Y)", I would like this string to be the filter condition in the filter function of a Dataframe. So an example will be like this:

```
condition = "col(X) | col(Y)"
dataFrame.filter(condition)
```

I saw on the documentation that I need an Expr to pass in the filter, but how can I transform a string to an Expr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), builtin-function from Python like so:

```
condition = "col(X) | col(Y)"
dataFrame.filter(eval(condition))
```

Comment: Didn't thought it will work, thanks !

Comment: Did work for me with the latest version of polar. Failed with error `NameError: name 'col' is not defined`

Comment: @ChitralVerma, if you have not directly imported `col` from `polars`, then you will get a `NameError`. Therefore, if you do the usual `import polars as pl`, then your string predicate would need to be `"pl.col(X) | pl.col(Y)"`, for example.