# Can I use a pandas-like string expression for filtering a DataFrame?

Tags: python-polars

I am considering replacing my use of `pandas` with `polars` in a tool that allows users to input predicate expressions for filtering/subsetting data rows. This allows users to use expressions that the `pandas.DataFrame.query` method can parse, such as `"x > 1"`, as a very simple example.

However, I can't seem to find a way to use the same types of string expressions with `polars.DataFrame.filter` so that I can swap out `pandas` for `polars` without requiring users to change their predicate expressions.

The only thing I've found that's close to my question is this posting: [String as a condition in a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72232027/string-as-a-condition-in-a-filter)

Unfortunately, that's not quite what I need, as it still requires a string expression like `"pl.col('x') > 1"` rather than simply `"x > 1"`.

Is there a way to use the simpler ("agnostic") syntax with `polars`?

Using the example from the `polars.DataFrame.filter` docs:

```py
>>> df = pl.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "foo": [1, 2, 3],
...         "bar": [6, 7, 8],
...         "ham": ["a", "b", "c"],
...     }
... )
```

When calling `df.filter`, I'm forced to use expressions like the following:

```py
pl.col("foo") < 3
(pl.col("foo") < 3) & (pl.col("ham") == "a")
```

However, I want to be able to use the following *string expressions* instead, respectively, so that the users of the tool (currently using `pandas`) do not have to be aware of the `polars`-specific syntax (thus allowing me to swap libraries without impacting users):

```py
"foo < 3"
"foo < 3 & ham == 'a'"
```

When I attempt to do so, here's what happens, which is puzzling since `str` is one of the supported types for the predicate argument, so it is unclear as to the syntax supported for `str` predicates since the docs do not show any examples of such:

```py
>>> df.filter("foo < 3")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/gedi_subset/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py", line 2565, in filter
    self.lazy()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/gedi_subset/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 391, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/gedi_subset/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 1165, in collect
    return pli.wrap_df(ldf.collect())
exceptions.NotFoundError: foo < 3
```

What I was expecting was the same return value that `df.filter(pl.col("foo") < 3)` would return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use the `SqlContext` for that.

```py
import polars as pl
ctxt = pl.SQLContext()

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3],
        "bar": [6, 7, 8],
        "ham": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)

ctxt.register("df", df.lazy())

string_expr = "foo < 3 and ham = 'a'"

(ctxt.query(f"""
SELECT * FROM df
WHERE {string_expr}
"""))
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────┐
│ x   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 3   │
└─────┘
```

Note that the `SQL` language doesn't use the bitwise `&` nor equality `==` the same way as pandas, so you might need to replace `&` with `and` and `==` with `=`.